# Binding custom event with Vue 2 and JSX

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to bind custom event on root tag instead of binding it in `mounted()`. So I try the following code:

```
render (h) {
  return (
    <div on-custom-event={this.handleCustomEvent}></div>
  )
}
```

But when I run it with Chrome, I found that `custom-event` was bound to DOM which cannot be fired using `$emit`, but with `VueJS 2`'s template syntax it is easy to do:

```
<template>
   <div @custom-event="handleCustomEvent"></div>
</template>
```

Please help me on this problem, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

A little bit late for the party but...

To trigger the event you need to something like:

```
protected render(h: any) {
    return (
        <a onClick={(e: any) => this.$emit('test')}>
            {this.$slots.default}
        </a>
    );
}
```

To listen to the event:

```
protected render(h: any) {
    return (
        <NavLink onTest={() => alert('clicked')}>
            <i class='fa fa-bars'></i>
        </NavLink>
    );
}
```

Comment: How to pass and capture the data between emitter and listener? I am trying this.$emit('test', 'testdata').......onTest={(data) => {alert(data);}}.....but, it's not working.

Answer (score 4):

According to example in [the docs](https://github.com/vuejs/babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx#difference-from-react-jsx), the JSX event handler should be camel-case, not kebab-case, so try something like:

```
render (h) {
  return (
    <div onCustomEvent={this.handleCustomEvent}></div>,
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I've already know it, my question is when I replace `click` to some non-native event, it will directly bind to DOM. What I want to achieve is like `this.$on('custom-event', this.customEventHandler)` will do.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your custom event is `custom-event`. Try either one of the following:

- `onCustom-event`
- `on-custom-event`

I found them here: https://github.com/vuejs/babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx/issues/164